# Here're the reasons I'm resigning, should I accept this counter offer?

Tags: job-offer, career-development, negotiation, benefits

I have another offer from a company other than the one I'm working for currently.
The reasons I'm looking to leave are:

1. I feel that I'm not gaining experience
2. No contract, nor insurance whatsoever, Also I'm working with my own laptop.
3. No clear plans (or at least, announced). Only a plan to start the product we're working on from scratch, since the current one is full of bad practices and outdated libraries (result of continues changing developers I think).

The only advantage that I find, Is that it's close to my home, Unlike the new offer, where the company is a bit further.

When I told my manager that I'm resigning, He tried to know why. He said "we can increase the salary", although I tried to negotiate with him about the salary before and he didn't agree to increase above a certain number.

He also said we have plans and many funds opportunities that're unannounced.
Also we can work on the insurance and whatsoever.

I'm really hesitated here, should I believe him ? I don't know what's lying ahead, but the new offer has a complete package of salary/insurance/contract.
Also I think I'll be gaining more experience, although I can't know for sure until I work there.

The really one point that pushing me toward accepting the counter offer is that the location is close to my home.

Comment: I would be hesitant to consider that "counter offer" as anything more than hot air until I saw it written down on a company letterhead and signed by someone in authority. Anything else means they're just stringing you along.

Comment: If he didn't offer a specific number, it is not a counter offer.

Comment: Read the answer of Justas. If you have no contract nor insurance you should not be using the distance to your house as your first priority IMHO

Comment: They're stringing you along until they can let you go at their convenience and not yours. Don't fall for it.

Comment: Just point 3 (the complete rewrite) is a massive red flag: http://onstartups.com/tabid/3339/bid/2596/Why-You-Should-Almost-Never-Rewrite-Your-Software.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should change the job because you have already mentioned the reasons why you're looking for a new position.

> When I told my manager that I'm resigning, He tried to know why. He
>   said "we can increase the salary", although I tried to negotiate with
>   him about the salary before and he didn't agree to increase above a
>   certain number.

If you will accept counter offer, you will lose the new position. Statistically, people who accept counter offers don't settle in a current position for a long time. Nor you neither your boss think about long term. You have lost motivation. The boss may need some time for replacement. Or plays with low ball offers until some limit.

Answer (score 3):

> The reasons I'm looking to leave are:
>
> I feel that I'm not gaining experience No contract, nor insurance
>   whatsoever, Also I'm working with my own laptop. No clear plans (or at
>   least, announced). Only a plan to start the product we're working on
>   from scratch, since the current one is full of bad practices and
>   outdated libraries (result of continues changing developers I think).
>   The only advantage that I find, Is that it's close to my home, Unlike
>   the new offer, where the company is a bit further.
>
> When I told my manager that I'm resigning, He tried to know why. He
>   said "we can increase the salary", although I tried to negotiate with
>   him about the salary before and he didn't agree to increase above a
>   certain number.
>
> He also said we have plans and many funds opportunities that're
>   unannounced. Also we can work on the insurance and whatsoever.
>
> I'm really hesitated here, should I believe him ?

You listed all the reasons why you were leaving, and none of them indicated "salary".

Now the counter offer is to increase your salary, and even with that you don't seem to have come to a salary you really want. Everything else is just hope and pray.

I'm not sure why you are hesitant at all. Nothing has really changed except a bit more salary.

The answer seems obvious: **Leave, and don't look back.**